# Onchange not working on next page Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am using checkbox on every row to do multi delete record in datatable. I want to show delete button only if any checkbox is checked. On first page, onchange is working. But on second page so on, onchange not working.

Below is my code :

```
$(".isdt-selected").on("change", function() {
      $(".isdt-selected").each(function(index, elem) {
        if($(elem).is(':checked')){
          $('#btn-delete-bulk').show();
          return false;
        }else{
          $('#btn-delete-bulk').hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: What means - "on next page, onchange not working"? How are pages loaded?

Comment: Are you reruning this code on every page? `window.onready` doesn't always trigger in my experience.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov, i mean on second page, that on change not working

Comment: @zergski, i put this code inside $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov, no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with below code :

```
"drawCallback": function(settings) {
        $(".isdt-selected").on("change", function() {
          $(".isdt-selected").each(function(index, elem) {
            if($(elem).is(':checked')){
              $('#btn-delete-bulk').show();
              return false;
            }else{
              $('#btn-delete-bulk').hide();
            }
         });
      });
```

I saw the reference from here https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".isdt-selected").on("change", function() {
        $(".isdt-selected").each(function(index, elem) {
            if($(elem).is(':checked')){
                $('#btn-delete-bulk').show();
                return false;
            }else{
                $('#btn-delete-bulk').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I already put my code inside $(document).ready(function() {, but not working

Comment: @Beginner actually there is a solution like this; If you reload this code every time the change function runs, the problem will be solved. But that's just the solution. Not true.

Comment: Since i am using datatable which is built in pagination, how i reload that code?

Comment: When the forward page button is pressed, you have to run these codes again. So instead of document ready function, you should write change function for forward page button.